# Is there a Entity Framework database context generator in Visual Studio 2017 for ASP.NET Core that does not require the Package Manager Console?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, dbcontext, package-managers

I want to scaffold an existing database in Core, and I can [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) the Package Manager *Console* (or dotnet) with:

```
scaffold-dbcontext -connection "Server=.\myserver;Database=mydatabase;
User ID=johnny;Password=johnny;Integrated Security=true;" 
-provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -context MyNewDbContext
```

Is there a way to do this through the IDE without the command line?  There is a right-click add for everything else, but I cannot find anything to create a new DbContext so that I can scaffold with the VS add scaffolding right-click add menus.  I do not mind typing.  I wanted to see if it was required to use the Command Line.

Also, is it possible to reference the connection in appsettings.json instead of using the entire connection string (e.g. ".\sqlserver;...")

There is no context generator for .NET *Core* using the VS2017 IDE that I can find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my free EF Core Power Tools extension!

Comment: You didn't put a link.  Is that against SO self-product-promotion terms?

Comment: Just install from the Tools, Extensions and Updates dialog in Visual Studio!

Comment: Works great, thanks. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools

Answer (score 1):

I've made that thing myself. Put the command into a `.cmd` file and then use [Open Command Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) extension to run it. By default it runs `.cmd` or `.bat` files by pressing `Shift+Alt+5`.

P.S. Unfortunately, I also keep the full connection string in `.cmd` file. No idea how to read it from `appsettings.json` except reading by some tricky Powershell command.